# Knockout template will not update list when adding to observable array

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a knockout template:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="myList">        
  // template stuff here                   
</script>
```

I call it in with the `foreach` option:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name:'myList', foreach: ItemList }"></div>
```

I get the view model form my controller and use the following Javascript to bind it:

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));                                        
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("contentsDetails"));
```

I return a few items from my controller and everything renders fine.

My problem is that if I add to my observable array

```
var itemToAdd = {
            Name:  ko.observable("name a"),
            Desc:  ko.observable("desc a")
 }

 viewModel.MyObservableArray().push(itemToAdd);
```

I have checked the array is observable using:

```
 console.log(ko.isObservable(viewModel.MyObservableArray));
```

It does not update the UI template by adding the new item to the list.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's this line:

```
viewModel.MyObservableArray().push(itemToAdd);
```

By putting brackets after `MyObservableArray`, you're accessing the *underlying* array, and directly pushing the value into it.  Knockout doesn't see this change.  Instead, call `.push` directly on the `observableArray`:

```
viewModel.MyObservableArray.push(itemToAdd);
```

This is a method in knockout that will update the underlying array *and* notify any subscribers of the change, and will result in the UI being updated.

Alternatively, you can keep it as you have it, but inform knockout that it has changed, which will trigger the updates:

```
viewModel.MyObservableArray().push(itemToAdd);
viewModel.MyObservableArray.valueHasMutated();
```

Comment: Just wanted to understand....
viewModel.MyObservableArray().push(itemToAdd);
 This pushes the value but it wil be no longer an observable kind of??

Comment: @G_S `viewModel.MyObservableArray()` returns the underlying native javascript array - the `observableArray` wrapper still exists around it.  If you push a value into the underlying array directly, knockout doesn't know you've done so.  The `observableArray` object redefines the array methods to both update the underlying native array, and provide notifications to anything depending on that `observableArray`.  That's why you can call `.valueHasMutated` on the `observableArray` after changing the underlying array - it still exists and can then update itself properly based on the new contents.

Comment: Perfect.. understood it.. Thanks @James Thorpe